# SHA1CryptoServiceProvider e SHA1Managed retornam resultados diferentes

Tags: c#, sha1

Preciso criptografar uma string usando o SHA1. Consegui criptografar usando a classe SHA1 desse modo:

```
 public string CriptSha1(string secret)
        {

            string result = "";

            byte[] key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);

            SHA1 sha1 = SHA1Managed.Create();

            byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(key);

            foreach (byte b in hash)
            {
                result += b.ToString();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Se por acaso criptografar a palavra `teste` a saída que tenho é:

> 4611115513881331821151451031201166997127855811595

Agora se eu criptografar usando a classe SHA1CryptoServiceProvider desse modo:

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider cryptTransformSHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
string hashSecret = BitConverter.ToString(cryptoTransformSHA1.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-","");
```

A saída que tenho é:

> 2E6F9B0D5885B6010F9167787445617F553A735F

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque ? ou qual a diferença dessas classes ?

Comment: Eu descobri que o que deixa a saída diferente é o BitConverter mas afinal qual é a maneira mais adequada ao criptografar em SHA1 usar o BitConverter ou apenas usar um ToString() ?

Answer (score 0):

Seu primeiro código está incompleto, apenas retorna os bytes e não está convertendo eles.

Essa linha:

```
result += b.ToString();
```

Deveria transformar pra hexadecimal, dessa forma:

```
result += b.ToString("X2");
```

> 2E6F9B0D5885B6010F9167787445617F553A735F

### [Ideone Exemplo](http://ideone.com/dRJcxW)